# Fedex Ground not showing

Tags: shipping-methods

I have tried everything, and still can't get ground shipping to show. I've changed the packaging method, I've turned off `Residential Delivery` (set to no), I've added `home delivery`. Nothing works.If there are any other suggestions, I'd sure appreciate the help. Currently using `Magento CE 1.9.4`

Answer (score 0):

The response is based on the total products weight (sum of all the products weight in cart).

1. So if the total weight is up to 70lbs - Ground Shipping will be shown.
2. If the weight is more than 70lbs - you can use Home delivery.
3. And if the weight is above 150lbs - you can use freight methods.

Another thing which may help you is setting `Residential Delivery` option to `No`.

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, I've enabled Home, Ground, 2-Day and Standard Overnight.
With residential set to "No" it displays only Ground, 2-Day and Standard Overnight.
With residential set to "Yes" it marks the shipping up and, below 70 Lbs. displays Home, 2-Day and Standard overnight.
When over 70 Lbs. is displays Ground, 2-Day and Standard overnight.
Note: The options for home vs. ground tested the opposite as described in the previous answer.